# Отдельный файл для import в Python

Tags: python

с увеличением программы появилась идея вынести все import в отдельный файл, то есть если я импортирую в любом файле файл imports то все импорты которые в нем записал активируются и в фале вызывающем его.
Так вот вопрос как? Как сделать такой вызов или какуето функцию или класс?

Comment: Автоматический запуск кода при импорте (кроме инициализаций) - в целом довольно плохая идея. Лучше импортировать нужные функции и вручную их вызвать.

Comment: (спасибо) Просто появилось множество распределенных файлов которые требуют один и тот же импорт, от чего то мысль казалась хорошей.

Comment: Автоматический запуск кода при импорте делает ваш модуль не универсальным: 1 - если вам не нужно чтобы код запустился сразу, вам нужно импорт делать там где вам нужно чтобы код выполнился. В целом лучше чтобы все импорты находились в начале файла (чтобы сразу были видны зависимости). 2 - повторный импорт не вызовет повторный запуск кода, поэтому все равно придется запускать функции вручную. Лучше собрать весь код, который нужно запускать, в одну функцию, ее импортировать и запускать.